# What will the return type of a function affact a program in C++

Tags: c++

Just curious about how the return type of a function will have an effect on the program in C++. For example, the following three functions will do the same stuff but have different return types:

```
void myfun();

int myfun();

bool myfun();
```

Suppose `void myfun()` will be enough for my purpose as there is no need to return a value. However, I may still consider to use `int myfun()` as with the evolution of the development it is possible that  this function need to return a value. So, if I use `int myfun()` rather than `void myfun()`, what kind of cost I will expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely bugger all. That's about equivalent to the cost of changing it. Don't give it a return value just because it might someday later need one. Keep it strictly to what you know you need.

Answer (score 1):

a very slight cost indeed to allocate memory to store the return value on the stack..

but for general SW design - refactoring it not a bad word! design and write your code to be simple... the thumb rule is **Simple is Better**. if you don't need an `int` return value - don't define it. if you'll need one in the future - refactor your code!

Comment: That seems like a voodoo answer. Have you got any machine code to back these claims up?

Comment: @KerrekSB to what claim are you referring? the first or the second

Comment: The claim about the cost of allocating memory and stacks and all.

Comment: @KerrekSB - i don't have such in hand, but i can build one... when i said *slight* i meant negligible, some CPU cycle/memory to allocate memory on stack and copy the return value on it.